# Wordpress: Why can subscribers see the admin panel?

Tags: wordpress, role

One of my clients is running a wordpress site with Woocommerce. I was recently asked to log in as one of their users, in order to replicate an issue.

What I found was that I can type /wp-admin and it just takes me to the full blown admin panel and I have all the same menu items as an admin. This is obviously very serious because if any of the users figures this out, they could take the site down if they wanted.

In an attempt to block them, I placed the following script in the functions.php file:

```
//  Redirect non-admins away from wp-admin
add_action( 'init', 'blockusers_init' );

function blockusers_init() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( is_admin() && ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) && ! ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
```

After logging in as a user that has a "subscriber" role, **current_user_can( 'administrator' )** returns **false** if I am on the front-end of the site, and it returns **true** if I go to /wp-admin.

Since the current user is only a subscriber, I assume it should return false everywhere.

I'm a bit stuck with this...and I don't know what I should look at next. (I tried the usual stuff like disabling all plugins, but the issue is still there). Do you guys have any idea about what I should be trying next?

Comment: have you clicked through the admin panel and checked that it is actually the admin panel and not the personal user settings admin panel?

Comment: Did you checked the "New User Default Role" option in the General settings ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause for the problem above was a hack in the site. I found some files in the root folder that shouldn't have been there. The temporary fix was to delete wp-admin and wp-includes and copy the folders from a fresh instalation. Now the subscribers can't view the admin panel anymore, and it redirects to the front end like it should. Now I have to scan the plugins folder to see if I find anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Your check is incorrect. You're doing `!wp_admin()`. It's true when you're **not** in admin panel, which is exact opposite of what you want.

```
add_action('init', 'blockusers_init');

function blockusers_init()
{
    if (is_admin() && !current_user_can('administrator') && !( defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX ))
    {
        wp_redirect(home_url());
        exit;
    }
}
```

Note, that it can be either `current_user_can('subscriber')` to target only subscribers, or `!current_user_can('administrator')` to target all non administrators, meaning editors, contributors, etc.

Whole situation is weird though. Normally, a subscriber can access admin panel, but they only can see dashboard and their profile. If they in fact can see whole admin panel, you should investigate the cause, as it's abnormal.
P.S. Are you sure they didn't give you admin account instead of subscribe to investigate?

Comment: Hi, yes you are absolutely correct. The ` ! ` was there by mistake. I didn't actually have it in my code. I'm sure the user was a subscriber, and I created another user so I can test and the result is the same: all users can access all the admin menu items.

And yes, the whole situation is weird. Any suggestions about what could cause this weird behaviour?

Comment: @user3015234 No definite suggestions, since I've no idea what kind of plugins and theme they use. But I guess a good start would be to disable plugins one by one and see if it changes anything, then change theme. If it helps, you will at least know where to look further. Also, check if default new role in settings is subscriber and not something else.